# Bootstrap 3.3.7 - form-inline - input and button same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The input and the button works correctly on the same line, but the input size is small and has room for it to be larger.

[image]

I would like it to be 100% full size, following the line below the input and button, you see? My HTML is:

```
<form class="form-inline"> 
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <input type="email" class="form-control emailNewsletter" placeholder="Your Email goes here">
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign Up!</button> 
    </div> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `.signup-form` to `display: flex;` and `flex: 1 0 auto;` puts the button next to the input field and let it take the full width. Only thing you need to do is setting the input field to 100% width.

```css
.form-inline {
  display: flex;
}

.signup-form {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.emailNewsletter {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group signup-form"> <input type="email" class="form-control emailNewsletter" placeholder="Your Email goes here"> </div>
  <div class="form-group"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign Up!</button> </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @AugustoDomingos If this answer worked for you, make sure to accept it as the best answer.