# How to create an input and button on the same line in Bootstrap 3.4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have seen some questions similar to this one, however, I think none of the answers provided in those questions hint me in the right direction that I am looking for.

What I am trying to create is an input and a button on the same line. The input will need to always take as much space as possible, no matter how small or big its parent element is. When resizing the screen, the input and button elements should still stay inline (i.e. responsive). This is what the result should look like:

[image: Result]

These were possible answers I could come up with, but none of these are what I am looking for:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>
            Not like this please:
          </p>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputLabel1">Label</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputText1" placeholder="Your value">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Action</button>
          <hr style="border-color: #ddd;" />
          <p>
            Also not like this please:
          </p>
          <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputLabel2">Label</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputLabel2" placeholder="Your value">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputLabel3">Label</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Your value">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Action</button>
          </div>
          <hr style="border-color: #ddd;" />
          <p>
            Or also not this:
          </p>

          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your value">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Action</button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--panel-body end-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Perhaps I could be using flexbox, but if anyone else could help me out here by directing me somewhere to a proper solution, I would be very interested in knowing anything related to this.

Some questions I have already checked:

- [Bootstrap 3.3.7 - form-inline - input and button same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52459563/bootstrap-3-3-7-form-inline-input-and-button-same-line)
- [Input and button in same line with Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815260/input-and-button-in-same-line-with-bootstrap)
- A bit Russian but: [Bootstrap / CSS - Input, button and select in the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521425/bootstrap-css-input-button-and-select-in-the-same-line)

Comment: Why don't you wrap them in columns, one `.col-xs-9` and one `.col-xs-3` for the button, it will inline them even on mobile and adapt to the parent width. Although, there might be some medium gap between them, from the columns padding.

Comment: Yes, I have thought of doing that as well @darklightcode but as you said, the padding is quite unwanted. Also when the button's content text is bigger than the column, stuff won't align just well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are so many ways to do this. First of all I suggest you to use Bootstrap 4 as it has more helpful classes and uses flexbox. In addition, consider to put the js before the `</body>` tag, for better page load, as Bootstrap documentation suggests:

> Place the following `<script>s` near the end of your pages, right before
>   the closing  tag, to enable them. jQuery must come first, then
>   Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins.

**Bootstrap 3** (with custom classes):

```css
.my-flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .my-flex .input-container {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  .my-flex button {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group my-flex">
              <div class="input-container">
                <label for="exampleInputLabel1">Label</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputText1" placeholder="Your value">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Fire this button</button>
            </div>

          </div>
          <!--panel-body end-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Another solution:*

```
  .my-flex .input-container {
    flex-basis: calc(100% - 75px);
  }
```

This `flex-basis: calc(100% - 75px)` means that the input will take all available space minus the button width (+ margin).

*Another solution:*

```
  .my-flex .input-container {
    flex-basis: 85%;
  }

  .my-flex button {
    flex-basis: 15%;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
```

**Bootstrap 4:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-row align-items-end">
              <div class="form-group col">
                <label for="exampleInputLabel1">Label</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputText1" placeholder="Your value">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group col-auto">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light">Action</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--panel-body end-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: SO snippets automatically deal with scripts in the manner as shown within the example I had provided. It is meant to keep scripts out of relevancy for the most part and keep code as minimal as possible (see [MCVE] for more information). My question did not concern page-load in the first place (still great to point it out though!). Also, the decision to choose Bootstrap 3 or Bootstrap 4 is not up to me, so I must make do with what I have. Otherwise, I would not have asked for Bootstrap 3 specifically.

Comment: I see that you are using the 75px to remove (the button width) from the flex-basis width. The button width is variable (any text value could be inside, I just used the word 'action' as an example) so I think hardcoding this seems like an obnoxious choice. If I remove the 75px from `flex-basis: calc(100% - 75px)`, it does not seem to harm the final appearance?

Comment: For your first comment, I just mention it keep in mind :) . For the second comment, you can set flex-basis 18% on the button for example, and 80% to the input container. But you should wrap the element on mobile.

Comment: Do you mean to set a flex-basis on the button 18%? Doesn't this mean you are trying to set a fixed width on the button? The goal of my question is not to set fixed widths. I would like to enter any type of text within the button and the button should grow or shrink depending on its value (which it does by default without adding any CSS whatsoever), the input to the left of it should grow or shrink depending on how much space is left after that. Does `flex-basis: calc(100%)` not suffice to just do exactly that? Or even `width: 100%` on the `.my-flex .input-container` for that matter?

Comment: flex-grow: 1; is what you need (to input container). Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Div that would serve as a parent div or row for 2 other divs with fixed width.

- `.inline-form` contains 2 divs; `.input-container` and
  `.button-container`.
- `.input-container` has display:inline-block and a fixed width of 80%.
- `.button-container` has display:inline-block and a
  a fixed width of 20%-1px.
- Set both divs to `float:left`, this would limit them to the specific line only.
- Add `padding-right` on `.input-container` for the space between the input and button.

```css
.inline-form {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.inline-form>div {
  float: left;
}

.inline-form .input-container {
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 80% !important;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.inline-form .button-container {
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: calc(20% - 1px) !important;
}

.inline-form .button-container button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputLabel1">Label</label>
            <div class="inline-form">
              <div class="input-container">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputText1" placeholder="Your value">
              </div>
              <div class="button-container">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Action</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--panel-body end-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```